# Non-linear movement of element relative to another element

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm moving an element relative to another element. Let's call them Element A and Element B.

For the simplicity of the quesiton, I kept only X axis.

```
var element_a_container_width = 200;
var element_b_container_width = 700;

// I get position of the mouse,
// it is this position of Element A
// is is: 0 to 200
var mouse_x = e.clientX;

// I calculate relative position (0 to 1),
// (so 0 - is start and 1 is end)
var percentage_x = element_a_container_width / mouse_x;

// I apply position to Element B,
// based on its coordinates (container width)
var element_b_position = percentage_x * element_b_container_width;
```

All is good. BUT. I need to apply position to Element B in a non linear way, for example:

- If mouse position is 0-50 - Element B should be always at 0.
- If mouse position is 150-200 - Element B should be always at its max position (`element_b_container_width`).
- If mouse position is 50-150 - Element B should move accordingly (from 0 to `element_b_container_width`)

I'm probably missing something obvious, but I can't figure out how to do this, every time something is off.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
var percentage_x = (mouse_x - 50)/100;
var element_b_position = 0
if (mouse_x > 150) {
  element_b_position = element_b_container_width
}
if (mouse_x >= 50 && mouse_x <= 150 ) {
  element_b_position = percentage_x * element_b_container_width
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But this way it does not change smoothly, percentage_x should be 0 when we are at 50 and 1 when we are at 150. In your example - percentage_x would be around 0.2 at 50 and around 0.8 at 150.

Comment: Nevemind, I figured it out, your reply led me in the right direction. It's `percentage_x = (mouse_x - 50) / (element_a_container_width - 100 )`. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "if(){}" to give a change. cpu cannot read your mind.

```
function fMouse (x) {
  if (x > 0 && x < 50) {
    return minvalue;
  } else if (x > 50 && x < 150) {
    return x;
  } else if (x > 150 && x < 200) {
    return maxvalue;
  }
}
```

Simple algorithm- you can change min-max value.

Comment: Please indent your code and while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @DebanjanB I agree with my being rude. But that was just because it was very basic thing.

Comment: But you are a expert in this field while OP maybe is a new-bie getting the hands dirty first time.

Comment: @DebanjanB Ok,I see